# Rename a column value if multiple conditions met

Tags: python, pandas

I want to rename the column value of Level if two condition met. If the Type is Medium and Level as level 1, I want to rename the Level as level.

```
Type     Level
High   level 1
High   level 2
Medium level 1
Low    level 1
Low    level 2
```

I tried the below using np.where and I successfully got the value changed but unfortunately all the other values have been changed to 'No Level'

```
df["Level"] = np.where((df["Type"] == "Medium") &
                                         (df["Level"] == "level 1"), 'late_assignment', 'No Level')
```

My exception is below and is there anyway we can achieve this?

```
Type     Level
High   level 1
High   level 2
Medium level
Low    level 1
Low    level 2
```

Comment: Don't use `np.where`, perform boolean indexing: `df.loc[(df["Type"] == "Medium") & (df["Level"] == "level 1"), 'Level'] = 'No Level'`

Comment: Note that you **can** use `np.where`, but it's not needed: `df['Level'] = np.where((df["Type"] == "Medium") &(df["Level"] == "level 1"), 'No Level', df['Level'])`